# Get duplicated row in two datatable using lambda expression

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 datatable with identical structure and some rows with duplicate keys. So I want to use lambda expression to get all the records in table 1 that have its keys duplicates with any row's keys in table 2. I tried to use this: assume that `item1` and `item2` is keys

```
Dim result as IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = table1.Asenumerable.Where(function(t1) _
table2.AsEnumerable().Any(function(t2) t1("item1") = t2("item1") _
andalso t1("item2") = t2("item2")))
```

But this code snippet always give me no result (`result.count = 0`) despite the fact that there's duplicate between 2 tables

P/S: sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try following:

```
' prepare HashSet from keys from table2 '
Dim table2Keys = new HashSet(Of Tuple(Of String, String))
set.UnionWith(table2.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) Tuple.Create(x("item1"), x("item2"))

' search table1 for duplicates '
Dim result = table1.Where(Function(x) table2Keys.Contains(Tuple.Create(x("item1", y("item2")))
```

It should have better performance then using `Any`, because `HashSet` lookup can be done in *O(1)*.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszel: thank for your attention. But I can't follow your approach, because my project is targeting .NET Framework 3.5 (base on customer requirement) so I can't user `Tuple`. Do you by any chance have a way to work around it?

Comment: You can implement `Tuple(Of T1, T2)` by your own.

Comment: I think `set.UnionWith(table1.` must be replace by `set.UnionWith(table2.`